# No module named networkx

Tags: arcpy, installation, networkx, python-window

I'm trying to import the module networkx with the Python console in ArcGIS, but I keep getting the error "no module named networkx".
I have installed it with the command "pip install networkx".

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Have you looked at this website: https://tereshenkov.wordpress.com/2016/08/04/using-conda-for-geospatial-python-development/?

Comment: Are you using the Python window of ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you didn't install networkx in the ArcGIS Python environment you are currently using in ArcGIS. To be sure, that you choose the right enviromnent you should change the working Directory to the Scripts Folder of the right Python environment, before installing networkx via `pip install networkx` command. E.g.:

ArcGIS Pro:

```
cd C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\Scripts
```

ArcGIS Desktop (32-bit):

```
cd C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.x\Scripts
```

ArcGIS Desktop (64-bit):

```
C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.x\Scripts
```

Comment: thank you very much, it worked!

Comment: that's great. If you want, you could mark my answer as accepted  (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)